# Unity UWP File IO denies access to Desktop and more?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, access-denied

I created a blank Unity project, built it for UWP and added one line of code:

```
File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Users\jtth\Desktop\cntrlRcrds-013.txt");
```

And I get back,

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Users\jtth\Desktop\cntrlRcrds-013.txt' is denied.
```

I have:
Checking Firewall
Made sure all folders/files in path weren't Read Only
Changed path to root C:\
Tried path into the Apps data folder
Ran Unity & VS as admin
Restarted my computer

What gives? Please advise.
NOTE: I am running this on 'Local Machine', not on the HoloLens. The HoloLens has a variety of access permission issues itself.

Comment: While dealing with files or folders in UWP, one important rule is [Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP is very sandboxed, you can't really access most folders or files through the application...

Try

```
File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "cntrlRcrds-013.txt"));
```

And put the file in the location that Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path points to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did my suggestion work?  My UWP app has no problems reading files from the location listed...

Comment: Yes, I should have specified that, apologies. I have a plugin that needs the file path, and seeing that this won't be possible aside from within the apps sandbox... Unfortunately this means I'll have to implement a work around. Something like, unity calls a web service running on a server which houses my files. Web service returns the file as a byte[] which, depending on plausibility, will be written as a 'new' file inside the sandbox. Then feed this path to get the desired result

Comment: In short, the hope was to avoid hindering performance with having to read files in an obscure manner.

Comment: There are ways to do local loopback which calls a local service which would have access to all the normal C# locations.  However there are severe restrictions with doing this method, if I recall correctly you wouldn't be able to post your app to the Windows Store.